# (Android) How to download https file or dropbox file from webview?

Tags: android, webview

I want to download the file in the dropbox.
When I click download button in the page of dropbox.

www.dropbox.com/s/gcvehjeeg0qexzk/kjh.autohousing-2.apk?dl=0

Then moveing to following url

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/apQGcKRHO0O6WmD5wf7y3BH4SPjYxaV3CkY2FTvAAfvQveLFh6dAxDbDWnyUKjjx?dl=1

```
URL url = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
```

But, the Error occurs when downloading.

> 12-12 12:41:24.432: W/System.err(7917): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/SVmfYhZSFOofGnp76crtCXFDWSywjA4HYCPaZhhqPlPjZH9mZMIfV3B9jcWRxC3H?dl=1
>   12-12 12:41:24.442: W/System.err(7917):   at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
>   12-12 12:41:24.442: W/System.err(7917):   at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:270)
>   12-12 12:41:24.442: W/System.err(7917):   at
>   java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)

When getting inputstream. I got upper error log.
What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you're going to ask a question that you want us to put effort into solving, put some effort into making that question presentable. That means every sentence starts with a capital letter, everything is spelled out, and the contractions have apostrophes, and no "plz" or "u."

Comment: @AlexK Thank you so much to teach me. :) I edited again. I don't know it is presentable. if there is something that I'm lack of something. then teach me. I'll fix my demerits. Thanks:)

Comment: it looks much better. Very readable now.

Comment: @AlexK Oh.. Thank you so much. I didn't know The others can edit my writing. It is my first asking. so, now I am learning so much:) Thank you for editing my question. it looks more good. hehe

Comment: link is giving 404 error in browser also , check your url.

Comment: @MohammadKhatri Thanks to comment. I forgot to explain download page.^^; https://www.dropbox.com/s/gcvehjeeg0qexzk/kjh.autohousing-2.apk?dl=0 and the url is changed whenever I clicked.